# Modifying spacing between paragraphs, but not before the first paragraph, in beamer

Tags: beamer, parskip

Consider the following `beamer` code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
\usecolortheme{crane}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}

Paragraph 1

Paragraph 2

\begin{block}{Block title}
    Paragraph 3

    Paragraph 4
\end{block}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This gets typeset like this:

[image: output of the above code]

I would, however, like to have some vertical spacing between "Paragraph 1" and "Paragraph 2", and between "Paragraph 3" and "Paragraph 4". In other words, I would like the document to look like this:

[image: desired output]

I'm wondering whether there is a way to automate spacing so that I don't have to keep adding `\vspace` between paragraphs manually. In other words, I would like to make some global changes so that spacing gets added before every paragraph apart from the first.

Changing `\parskip` globally does not work because the space is added before *each* paragraph, Including "Paragraph 3" and "Block title" -- the output of that looks like this:

[image: undesired output obtained by changing \parskip]

**EDIT:** I know how to add the space manually, but that can be a bit annoying. I am wondering whether one can automate these things somehow.

Answer (score 3):

You can always force some space between paragraphs with `\smallskip`, `\medskip` and `\bigskip`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berkeley}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{title}
Paragraph1

\smallskip
Paragraph2
\begin{block}{This is a block}
Paragraph3

\medskip
Paragraph4
\end{block}
Pargraph5

\bigskip
Pargraph6

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Indeed, `beamer` deliberately alters a lot of spacing stuff: anything like this needs to be done by hand.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know how to do this manually, but it's annoying to keep repeating it so I was wondering whether it can be automated.